# Java: Open URL in browser popup window in center of screen

Tags: java

I can't seem to find answer anywhere but How can I open URL in default-set browser, but not typical full screen browser but a small window in center of monitor?

I have Java application which uses Flickr API, when user logins it needs to open small window to show Authorize App or not, full screen huge window looks stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution will be to use JavaFX WebView 
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/SimpleSwingBrowser.java.htm
You can set the window size and window location to the main Frame.
Also If you like, it can integrate to your app like a internal panel or like a Dialog.